# Modify the settings of Android device

Tags: android

I am using Location Service in my app as follows:

```
LocationManager locM = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);                
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
            criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);


            String currentProvider = locM.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Log.d("Location", "currentProvider: " + currentProvider);


            Location currentLocation = locM.getLastKnownLocation(currentProvider);

            if(currentLocation == null){
                locM.requestLocationUpdates(currentProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
```

And I add permissions of network and locations in Manifest.xml.
When I test this code in my Android phone earlier today, this line `String currentProvider = locM.getBestProvider(criteria, true);` always returned null. After some googling, I find out that this is caused by the settings of my phone. I should turn settings->location->use wireless networks on.

I am curious that why other app(e.g. google maps) can work well even when I turn this off. Because I never modify the settings of location before, and all other apps using location service in my phone works well. **Is there some way to modify settings in code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find out that there are lots of third-party libraries that works much better than the built-in location classes. Like baidu in china. Plz refer to this page:[Wiki of baidu Location sdk](http://developer.baidu.com/map/geosdk-android-developv3.3.htm)